# WPF Listview touch issue on window 10: "an event of another datatemplate is triggered while it may not happen"

Tags: wpf, listview, events, touch, datatemplate

When using a WPF application on windows 10 **with a touchscreen** we encounter an issue with the listview. When working with a mouse it works fine.

We have created a simple test-project, which is used to simulate the problem on windows 10 and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/KafProjects/WPFListViewIssues). A ticket is also created on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ea3bff6-2b22-4451-86f8-9c4e6c3d7f35/wpf-listview-touch-issue-on-window-10-an-event-of-another-datatemplate-is-triggered-while-it-may?forum=wpf)

In short below a summary of the technical setup:

- We use a grouped listview, and for each group, a togglebutton and
  another (inner) listview.
- The inner listview uses an ItemTemplateSelector binded to an
  Datatemplate selector, to choose an datatemplate.
- There are 3 datatemplates (checkbox, numeric, text) that will be
  choosen based upon the type property of the bounded model.
- Each datatemplate has a stackpanel. The stackpanel in the text en
  numeric datatemplate is wired to an PreviewMouseDown event. 
  Important, the stackpanel in the checkbox isn't wired to an event.

> This works in general well, however sometimes, when touching the checkbox, the
>   PreviousMouseDown of another template is triggered.

**I would expect that this behavior may not happen, is that correct?**

> We found a workaround **(*)** for this issue but we didn't find the root
>   cause.

**Why is the event of another template triggered?**

> I'm starting to believe that this could be an issue with WPF Listview
>   and touch behavior?

**(*)** If we know that sometimes an event is triggered from a wrong template,
we verify every event whether that event is originated  from the right template and if not we do nothing.

Below you can see when tapping quickly on the checkbox the clickevent get's triggered.

[image: isuses]

Below more details of the code:

- The datatemplates and the selector

[image: datatemplates]

- The grouped listview with the inner listview and the itemtemplate selector

[image: listview]

- Below the code behind and the handler for the PreviewMouseDown event

[image: codebehind]

> Below an overview of the  steps we have been taken in order to resolve
>   it, but none lead into a solution.

[image]

Comment: Known issue? https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/194

Comment: @I33t, indeed also a wpf-touch issue, however the code setup is different, and therefore I assume that the rootcause is also different, but not sure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WPF is supporting touch and a touch on a screen is also "translated" into a mousedown event, I don't see a problem why not using a previewMouseDown event on a touch screen. I also didn't find any offical documentation of Microsoft in not doing this.

Anyway, I could no longer reproduce the problem that a touch on listviewitem is invoking another previeuwMouseDown event of a template of another listviewitem in the list by ....

> Changing the PrevieuwMouseDown event by a Touchdown event!

I am glad to find a solution, however based upon many online searches, I feel there are many issues with thouch on WPF and often it's is not clear what the rootcause is. Like in this case I found a solution by trial and error, but why the problem occurs when using previewMouseDown, is puzzling.